# How can I chain promises sequentially running a mocha integration test?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I want to test two or more promises like an integration test and they should run in sequence. Example is obviously wrong because I get as a user the property from the previous test only (email).

Note that I am using chai-as-promised here but I don't have to if there is a simpler solution.

*userStore returns a promise and I can resolve it if its only a one-liner in other tests without a problem.*

```
    it.only('find a user and update him',()=>{
    let user=userStore.find('testUser1');

    return user.should.eventually.have.property('email','testUser1@email.com')
        .then((user)=>{
            user.location='austin,texas,usa';
            userStore.save(user).should.eventually.have.property('location','austin,texas,usa');
        });

});
```

If I use return `Promise.all` then it is not guaranteed to run sequentially right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When chaining promises, you have to ensure to *always `return`* the promises from *every* function, including `.then()` callbacks. In your case:

```
it.only('find a user and update him', () => {
    let user = userStore.find('testUser1');
    let savedUser = user.then((u) => {
        u.location = 'austin,texas,usa';
        return userStore.save(u);
//      ^^^^^^
    });
    return Promise.all([
        user.should.eventually.have.property('email', 'testUser1@email.com'),
        savedUser.should.eventually.have.property('location', 'austin,texas,usa')
    ]);
});
```

Comment: I tried that but the user parameter in the second chained promise is the string 'testUser1@email.com' that is probably returned from chai should.

Comment: @arisalexis: Can you try `Promise.all([user, user.should.eventually.…]).then(([user]) => … )`?

Comment: so the key to testing different stuff is to keep a reference like a snapshot to the promise you want tested. that is what I was looking for yes.

Comment: @Bergi - "..you have to ensure to *always* `return` promises..".  This is not so, as  `then()` will map the return value of the function into a promise, even if it's a generic value.  For example:  `Promise.resolve('done')
  .then(function(value) {
          return 'Yabadabadoo';
        })
   .then(console.log.bind(console))     // Yabadabadoo
   .catch(console.error.bind(console));`

Comment: @caasjj: Sure it does. What I meant was that you always need to return promises *when the function does something asynchronous*, I omitted this subclause here as all the functions in the question were async.

Answer (score 0):

**ES7 with async:**

```
it.only('find async a user and update him',async ()=>{

        let user=await userService.find('testUser1');
        expect(user).to.have.property('email','testUser1@email.com');
        user.location = 'austin,texas,usa';
        let savedUser=await userService.update(user);
        expect(savedUser).to.have.property('location','austin,texas,usa');
});
```

Comment: I think es7 is called? and I just put the current year so its visible. don't know how to format it.

Comment: Yeah, ES7 == ES2016. But don't mix the two :-)